# share to google classroom button not rendering

Tags: angularjs, google-classroom

I want to add Share to google classroom button to angularjs app. It is not rendering however. Has anyone have same problem and found solution for it?
I have added script to index.html in

```
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```

and div with button in different places including index.html and some custom components.

```
<div class="g-sharetoclassroom" data-size="32" data-url="http://www.wp.pl" ></div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround. I use explicit render

```
    <script>
      window.___gcfg = {
        parsetags: 'explicit'
      };
      function renderWidget() {
        gapi.sharetoclassroom.render("widget-div",
            {"url": "http://www.google.com"} );
      }
    </script>
```

I have not work out every detail yet, but the button is displaying.